After replacing datadog java agent with the opentelemetry java agent, metrics are not flowing to the datadog backend
We have datadog setup in our organisation for monitoring. 
We use datadog to check the metrics and view the exception. We don't use it to see the logs.
We are planning to replace the datadog javaagent with opentelementry javaagent(due to better instrumentation support for vert.x) but keep our metrics that is flowing to the datadog backend intact.
We are following the documentation https://docs.datadoghq.com/opentelemetry/interoperability/otlp_ingest_in_the_agent/?tab=host

Our configuration for opentelementry java agent(Version 2.3.0) is
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_LOGS_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/logs
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/metrics
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/{signal}
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/traces
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=supply

Datadog agent version - 7.51.0 and configuration


## OTLP ingest related configuration
  otlp:
    receiver:
      protocols:
        # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.grpc - OTLP/gRPC configuration
        grpc:
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.grpc.enabled -- Enable the OTLP/gRPC endpoint
          enabled: false
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.grpc.endpoint -- OTLP/gRPC endpoint
          endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.grpc.useHostPort -- Enable the Host Port for the OTLP/gRPC endpoint
          useHostPort: true

        # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.http - OTLP/HTTP configuration
        http:
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.http.enabled -- Enable the OTLP/HTTP endpoint
          enabled: true
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.http.endpoint -- OTLP/HTTP endpoint
          endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"
          # datadog.otlp.receiver.protocols.http.useHostPort -- Enable the Host Port for the OTLP/HTTP endpoint
          useHostPort: true
    logs:
      # datadog.otlp.logs.enabled -- Enable logs support in the OTLP ingest endpoint
      enabled: false



Goal -> We want to send the metrics to the datadog backend using the datadog agent by the opentelemetry instrumentation(java agent) as shown in the image above.
We are able to access the datadog agent http://:4318/v1/metrics from the service pod where we added the open telementry instrumentation.
We are unable to view the metrics for the service in the datadog UI for the service instrumented with opentelementry java agent.
We are seeing one exception in that service pod logs file
[otel.javaagent 2024-05-14 16:10:24:760 +0530] [OkHttp http://172.31.22.114:4318/...] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.http.HttpExporter - 
Failed to export logs. Server responded with HTTP status code 404. Error message: Unable to parse response body, HTTP status message: Not Found


Would you mind getting rid of LOGS, METRICS and TRACES endpoints and using only the following one, like that: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318
Also the error is related to logs, do you have metrics exporter errors?

If you don't want to send OTel logs to anywhere, you can set the following env var: OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=none, same works for Traces.

Setting OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=none, removes the exception. We are not able to see any errors with the metrics exporter.

We do tried hitting the metrics url directly with the json that we got when we set the OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=logging-otlp. We got the response as {"partialSuccess":{}}. The metric is though not visible on the datadog UI. I am assuming that there something to do with the otlp version mismatch between javaagent and datadog agent.

Our first configuration was only OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://:4318 and OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=supply but  still we were not able to see any metrics flowing to datadog UI.

It was flowing but with env=null, just checked. Thank you @JulianoCosta

Awesome! Let us know if something else doesn't work. I'll post an answer shortly

Everything seems to be properly configured, except your environment variables.
You have to either use the OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_<SIGNAL>_ENDPOINT with the full path, or OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT just till port.
Eg.:
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_LOGS_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/logs
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/metrics
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318/v1/traces

or
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://<datadog agent ip>:4318

The OTel Agent will append /v1/<signal> automatically when using the 2nd approach.
Also, you can configure the OTel agent to suppress a signal if you do not want to send it anywhere, using the following environment variables:
OTEL_<SIGNAL>_EXPORTER=none

